# Android: Showing keypad at scrolling of page

Tags: android, keyboard, scrollbar

How to show the keypad even when the page is being scrolled up in android to fill text in textfield. Following is my problem scenario:
I have 1 login page:

1) I tap on "Username" field.
2) Keypad opens up.
3) Now scroll up login page.

Issue : Keypad got closed when we scroll up login page.

But I want it should not get hidden

How to solve this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your keypad doesn't automatically pop up, you can call it by long-pressing the menu button in any app or web setting. This should work for any device running Android.